# When does paraphrasing become copyright infringement?

Tags: copyright

For specific context, Let's say I am currently taking notes for my own personal use. Whenever I find useful information on webpages, I paraphrase the information into my own words and type them into a simple word document which I save. For this document, I don't intend on distributing it to anyone and don't plan on using it for any profit or commercial use. Would this specific example be considered legal and not copyright infringement?

Comment: See also: [How much change to a company’s copyrighted picture is needed?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/79974/how-much-change-to-a-company-s-copyrighted-picture-is-needed)

Comment: [In the UK](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/exceptions-to-copyright) you can make a single copy for **non-commercial** personal use e.g. study. But you don't indicate precisely what you are using the copy for.

Comment: Which country are you asking about?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by "paraphrase". If you don't copy the actual words of a document and only write down the ideas contained therein (using your own words), that is a traditional paraphrase, and it is legal. You can even sell your paraphrase document. If you copy and then modify the original text (changing some words here and there), then that is copyright infringement. You can probably defend yourself against an infringement lawsuit using the fair use defense, if it's not redistributed.